# Yet another abstract class issue in C++ with closures

Tags: c++, c++11, closures, lambda, class-hierarchy

I have a problem compiling this code with `g++ -std=c++11` argument:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;;

template <typename T> class opt {
    public:
        opt() {};
        ~opt() {};
        virtual int isEmpty() = 0;
        virtual T getObject() = 0;
};

template <typename T> class oopt : public opt<T> {
    private:
        T ret;
    public:
        oopt(T obj) { ret = obj; };
        ~oopt() override;
        int isEmpty() { return 0; };
        T getObject() { return ret; };
};
int main(void) {

    function<opt<int>(int)> fu = [](int j) { return (oopt<int>(10)); };

    return 1;
}
```

This code returns the following error:

```
assoc_array.cc: In instantiation of ‘class oopt<int>’:
assoc_array.cc:68:63:   required from here
assoc_array.cc:29:3: error: ‘oopt<T>::~oopt() [with T = int]’ marked override, but does not override
In file included from assoc_array.cc:3:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/functional: In instantiation of ‘static _Res std::_Function_handler<_Res(_ArgTypes ...), _Functor>::_M_invoke(const std::_Any_data&, _ArgTypes ...) [with _Res = opt<int>; _Functor = main()::<lambda(int)>; _ArgTypes = {int}]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:2298:6:   required from ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor, typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_integral<_Functor>::value), std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Useless>::type) [with _Functor = main()::<lambda(int)>; _Res = opt<int>; _ArgTypes = {int}; typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_integral<_Functor>::value), std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Useless>::type = std::function<opt<int>(int)>::_Useless]’
assoc_array.cc:68:67:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:1909:7: error: invalid abstract return type for function ‘static _Res std::_Function_handler<_Res(_ArgTypes ...), _Functor>::_M_invoke(const std::_Any_data&, _ArgTypes ...) [with _Res = opt<int>; _Functor = main()::<lambda(int)>; _ArgTypes = {int}]’
assoc_array.cc:7:29: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘opt<int>’:
assoc_array.cc:11:15: note:     int opt<T>::isEmpty() [with T = int]
assoc_array.cc:12:13: note:     T opt<T>::getObject() [with T = int]
In file included from assoc_array.cc:3:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:1912:40: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘opt<int>’
assoc_array.cc:7:29: note:   since type ‘opt<int>’ has pure virtual functions
In file included from assoc_array.cc:3:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:1743:2: error: ‘static _Functor* std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<_Functor>::_M_get_pointer(const std::_Any_data&) [with _Functor = main()::<lambda(int)>]’, declared using local type ‘main()::<lambda(int)>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
```

Where is my error using the closures with the static casting to an interface? I've already read similar replies ([C++ and inheritance in abstract classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785207/c-and-inheritance-in-abstract-classes), [C++ - "Member function not declared" in derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615902/c-member-function-not-declared-in-derived-class)), but it seems that no error is given at compile time if I remove the closure definition. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Even with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;;

template <typename T> class opt {
    public:
        opt<T>(T) {};
        ~opt<T>() {};
        virtual int isEmpty() = 0;
        virtual T getObject() = 0;
};

template <typename T> class oopt : public opt<T> {
    private:
        T ret;
    public:
        oopt<T>(T obj) { ret = obj; };
        ~oopt<T>() override;
        int isEmpty() { return 0; };
        T getObject() { return ret; };
};
int main(void) {

    function<opt<int>(int)> fu = [](int j) { return (oopt<int>(10)); };

    return 1;
}
```

I still have the following compiling issues:

```
assoc_array.cc: In instantiation of ‘class oopt<int>’:
assoc_array.cc:26:64:   required from here
assoc_array.cc:20:4: error: ‘oopt<T>::~oopt() [with T = int]’ marked override, but does not override
assoc_array.cc: In instantiation of ‘oopt<T>::oopt(T) [with T = int]’:
assoc_array.cc:26:64:   required from here
assoc_array.cc:19:19: error: no matching function for call to ‘opt<int>::opt()’
assoc_array.cc:19:19: note: candidates are:
assoc_array.cc:9:4: note: opt<T>::opt(T) [with T = int]
assoc_array.cc:9:4: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
assoc_array.cc:7:30: note: constexpr opt<int>::opt(const opt<int>&)
assoc_array.cc:7:30: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
In file included from assoc_array.cc:3:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/functional: In instantiation of ‘static _Res std::_Function_handler<_Res(_ArgTypes ...), _Functor>::_M_invoke(const std::_Any_data&, _ArgTypes ...) [with _Res = opt<int>; _Functor = main()::<lambda(int)>; _ArgTypes = {int}]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:2298:6:   required from ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor, typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_integral<_Functor>::value), std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Useless>::type) [with _Functor = main()::<lambda(int)>; _Res = opt<int>; _ArgTypes = {int}; typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_integral<_Functor>::value), std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Useless>::type = std::function<opt<int>(int)>::_Useless]’
assoc_array.cc:26:68:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:1909:7: error: invalid abstract return type for function ‘static _Res std::_Function_handler<_Res(_ArgTypes ...), _Functor>::_M_invoke(const std::_Any_data&, _ArgTypes ...) [with _Res = opt<int>; _Functor = main()::<lambda(int)>; _ArgTypes = {int}]’
assoc_array.cc:7:30: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘opt<int>’:
assoc_array.cc:11:16: note:     int opt<T>::isEmpty() [with T = int]
assoc_array.cc:12:14: note:     T opt<T>::getObject() [with T = int]
In file included from assoc_array.cc:3:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:1912:40: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘opt<int>’
assoc_array.cc:7:30: note:   since type ‘opt<int>’ has pure virtual functions
In file included from assoc_array.cc:3:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:1743:2: error: ‘static _Functor* std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<_Functor>::_M_get_pointer(const std::_Any_data&) [with _Functor = main()::<lambda(int)>]’, declared using local type ‘main()::<lambda(int)>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you even use eopt in main, just get rid of it for our sake

Comment: eopt is used in some part of the code that is not interested in the descripted error.

Comment: Exactly when you post on SO it is in everyones best interest to make the code as simple as possible

Comment: Ok, done. I've edited the post above with the code corrections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, hope that my solution is correct: at least it compiles :). I'll leave that as an answer in order to receive additional comments concerning the solution. Thanks again.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

//I need shared_pointers in order to gain the C++ dynamic casting
template <typename T> class Ptr {
    shared_ptr<T> ptr;

    public:
        Ptr(T* obj) : ptr{obj} {};
        Ptr(shared_ptr<T> obj) : ptr{obj} {};

        ~Ptr() {  };

        template <typename U> Ptr<U> Cast();

        T* operator->() const  {return &(*this->ptr);}
        operator T() const { return (*this->ptr); };

};

template <typename T> template <typename U> Ptr<U> Ptr<T>::Cast(){
    return Ptr<U>{dynamic_pointer_cast<U>(ptr)};
};


template <typename T> class opt {
    protected:
        T ret;                
    public:
       ~opt() {};
       virtual int isEmpty() = 0;
       virtual T* getObject() = 0;
       operator T() const { return ret; }; 
};

template <typename T> class oopt : public opt<T> {
    public:
    oopt(T obj) { 
        this->ret = obj; 
    };  
    int isEmpty() { return 1; };
    T* getObject() { return &this->ret; }
};

template <typename T> class eopt : public opt<T> {
    public:
    eopt() { };  //for downcasting matters
    T* getObject() { return nullptr; } //
    int isEmpty() { return 1; };
};

int main(void) {

    Ptr<oopt<int>> u(new oopt<int>(500));
    Ptr<opt<int>> w = u.Cast<opt<int>>();
    cout << (*(w->getObject())) << "\n" ;

    Ptr<opt<int>> none(new eopt<int>());
    w = none.Cast<opt<int>>();
    if ((w->getObject()) == nullptr) {
        cout << "null" << "\n";
    }

    return 1;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

as gcc is the standard compiler around, his errors are not the most clears, even more with C++ than C, so i generally compile everything with both clang and gcc just to be sure.
compiled with clang:
i've got this with aaronman code, t

```
clang++ -std=c++11 test.cc                                                                                                                                                                              ~
test.cc:20:20: error: only virtual member functions can be marked 'override'
        ~oopt<T>() override;
                   ^~~~~~~~
test.cc:26:54: note: in instantiation of template class 'oopt<int>' requested here
    function<opt<int>(int)> fu = [](int j) { return (oopt<int>(10)); };
                                                     ^
test.cc:19:9: error: constructor for 'oopt<int>' must explicitly initialize the base class 'opt<int>' which does not have a default constructor
        oopt<T>(T obj) { ret = obj; };
        ^
test.cc:26:54: note: in instantiation of member function 'oopt<int>::oopt' requested here
    function<opt<int>(int)> fu = [](int j) { return (oopt<int>(10)); };
                                                     ^
test.cc:7:29: note: 'opt<int>' declared here
template <typename T> class opt {
                            ^
2 errors generated.
```

and this for your first:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 test2.cc                                                                                                                                                                             ~
test2.cc:20:17: error: only virtual member functions can be marked 'override'
        ~oopt() override;
                ^~~~~~~~
test2.cc:26:54: note: in instantiation of template class 'oopt<int>' requested here
    function<opt<int>(int)> fu = [](int j) { return (oopt<int>(10)); };
                                                     ^
1 error generated.
```

after fixing these errors clang gave me this during linking:

```
clang++ -o -std=c++11 test2.o -Wall -Werror                                                                                                                                                             ~
test2.o: In function `std::_Function_handler<opt<int> (int), main::$_0>::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&, int)':
test2.cc:(.text+0x1a7): undefined reference to `oopt<int>::~oopt()'
test2.o:(.rodata._ZTV4ooptIiE[_ZTV4ooptIiE]+0x10): undefined reference to `oopt<int>::~oopt()'
test2.o:(.rodata._ZTV4ooptIiE[_ZTV4ooptIiE]+0x18): undefined reference to `oopt<int>::~oopt()'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocati
```

on)

it's not a precise answer, but this could help a lot

Comment: Thanks: the main problem is that some things are compiled by g++ but not by clang++. By the way, I'm actually working to the solution...

Answer (score 0):

Ok first get rid of the override and make the destructor virtual (they should always be when inherited). Also the destructor is unimplemented in the base class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;;

template <typename T> class opt {
    public:
        opt() {};
        virtual ~opt() {};
        virtual int isEmpty() = 0;
        virtual T getObject() = 0;
};

template <typename T> class oopt : public opt<T> {
    private:
        T ret;
    public:
        oopt(T obj) { ret = obj; };
        ~oopt(){};
        int isEmpty() { return 0; };
        T getObject() { return ret; };
};
int main(void) {

    function<opt<int>(int)> fu = [](int j) { return (oopt<int>(10)); };

    return 1;
}
```

This compiles now. As for the errors you were getting originally I can't say as to where they were coming from since I didn't get them

Comment: well, in oopt definition I state that:

`oopt(T obj) { ret = obj; };`

so, with `T = int`, I have an int constructor: so I must implement it as follows even for the superclass?

Comment: That is `oopt` not `opt`, honestly this is difficult to read consider giving your classes more descriptive names or shortening the code to put it on SO

Comment: Well, given your code, I still have the following error: http://pastebin.com/BphD63pu

Comment: Either you aren't using c++11 or you are including something your not showing me

Comment: Well,I simply compile with `g++ -std=c++11 -c assoc_array.cc`, and using only the code you posted. I don't really know what to say. I get the same errors on two different computers.

Comment: Yep, that's the strange thing.